# What is required for a proper boost chainline on a 1x drivetrain - only a boost chainring or an entire crankset?

Tags: crankset, chainring, chainline, boost

To obtain a proper chainline for a boost rear hub (~52 mm), is it enough to fit a boost (3 mm offset) chainring to a 1x crankset which is originally non-boost, or is an entire boost crankset required (i.e. not only the chainring but also the crankarms)? Namely, I am buliding a boost bike and can get a very good deal for a SRAM groupset that has a non-boost DUB direct mount crankset. The simplest and cheapest way to go for me would be to buy the groupset and replace only the non-boost chainring (6 mm offset) with a boost variant (3 mm offset), while keeping the rest of the crankset. Would this work?

Comment: I've done a little research in the meantime, and, at least for SRAM cranksets, it looks like changing the chainring is enough. That is according to page 14 of their [Chainrings and Spider User Manual](https://www.sram.com/sites/default/files/techdocs/95-6218-005-000_rev_b_chainrings_and_spider_user_manual.pdf). In particular for all DUB and 24 mm spindle cranksets, it seems that one should use 6 mm offset chainring to get non-boost, 49 mm chainline, and 3 mm offset chainring for boost, 52 mm chainline. However, I'd like to confirm this with someone who has actually dealt with this issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've got it right, at least in terms of the current SRAM direct mount cranks (i.e. that the cranks themselves are same, and the only thing that makes a crank the boost version is it comes with a 3mm offset ring as opposed to 6mm).

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** The entire boost system has to be used with all the pieces together to have a proper chainline 53 mm to my taste.

I've already had a boost hub, and a non boost entire crankset. At the end of the first month the chain touched the frame. On a race I confirmed a noisy chain, and finally had some missed shifts (twice).

Exactly what I have been searching for 3 weeks now, and found that as SRAM and one up moves the just chainring, and Shimano offer change the crankarms.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what exactly you mean with "i found that as SRAM and one up moves the just chainring, and Shimano offer change the crankarms." ?
Thank you!

Comment: Concur - I'm not sure what point you're making in the (now) last line.  Can you please [edit] that to explain further?   BTW, welcome to SE and thank you for your first post... do take a moment to read the [tour] to learn how the site works.